# After upgrading to Expo48 Meeting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exists')

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, expo

After upgrading my project from Expo45 to Expo48, I encounter this error when running the test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exists')
at exists (node_modules/expo-asset/src/PlatformUtils.ts:65:17)  
at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)  
at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
```

The unit test itself is quite simple:

```
  it('Should be able rendered properly', () => {
    render(
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={[initialState, jest.fn()]}
      >
        <UpdatePasswordScreen />
      </UserContext.Provider>,
    );
  });
```

The UpdatePasswordScreen component is like this:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Spinner
        visible={showSpinner}
        textContent={'Loading...'}
        textStyle={{
          color: '#FFFFFF',
        }}
      />
      <CustomInput
        titleStyle={{
          size: 13,
        }}
        titleContainerStyle={{
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          marginBottom: 8,
        }}
        placeholder="Enter Password"
        title="Old password"
        value={oldPassword}
        secureTextEntry={!showOldPassword}
        onRenderLeftIcon={() => (
          <Icon
            name={showOldPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
            type="feather"
            size={20}
            color="#AFB4B9"
            onPress={() => setShowOldPassword(!showOldPassword)}
          />
        )}
        onChangeText={setOldPassword}
      />
      <View style={styles.confirmButton}>
        <IconButton
          text="Reset Password"
          buttonStyle={{
            height: 52,
            width: 200,
          }}
          onPress={updatePassword}
          disabled={!oldPassword || !newPassword
            || !confirmNewPassword || showPasswordErrorMessage()
            || newPassword !== confirmNewPassword
            || oldPasswordUnchanged
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

I just want to render the component but it doesn't work. The unit test run well under Expo45.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this error by adding these lines to my jest setup file :

```
jest.mock("expo-font");
jest.mock("expo-asset");
```

Comment: Thanks!, but does anyone know why does the solution above works?